# Understanding Generic FromIterator in Rust

Tags: generics, rust, linked-list, iterator, traits

I am new to rust and I found myself lost in this second line. How can I interpreted it? Which one would be the interator that I can use to do the conversion to `SimpleLinkedList`?

```
impl<T> FromIterator<T> for SimpleLinkedList<T> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(_iter: I) -> Self {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found myself lost in this second line. How can I interpreted it?

What part? `from_iter` is defined as a generic function parameterized on a type `I`. That type is then bounded on (meaning it must implement) `IntoIterator<Item=T>`.

`IntoIterator<Item=T>` means the type can be iterated (converted to an `Iterator`) and yields `T`. In the lingo of other languages, it's an itera*ble* of Ts.

So `from_iter` is a generic function whose input is an itera*ble* (`IntoIterator`) of whatever items the `SimpleLinkedList` should contain.

> Which one would be the interator

`_iter.into_iter()` would be the input iterator. You can also just iterate on `_iter` using a for loop, as it implicitly converts its RHS to an iterator using the `IntoIterator` trait.

Answer (score 2):

It looks intimidating at first but the implementation is very simple.

```
impl<T> FromIterator<T> for SimpleLinkedList<T> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(iter: I) -> Self {
        let mut list = SimpleLinkedList::new();
        for item in iter {
            list.push(item);
        }
        list
    }
}
```

The key thing to know is that types which implement the trait [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) can be used in `for-in` loops. The `Item = T` just means the iterator returns items of type `T`. You just iterate over `iter` and push the items into your `SimpleLinkedList` struct to do the conversion.

Comment: Also, very useful! Thanks for the answer